# How to extract usernames out of Tweets?

Tags: regex, twitter

I have the following example tweet:

```
RT @user1: who are @thing and @user2?
```

I only want to have *user1*, *thing* and *user2*.

What regular expression can I use to extract those three names?

PS: A username must only contain letters, numbers and underscores.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tested:

```
/@([a-z0-9_]+)/i
```

---

In Ruby (irb):

```
>> "RT @user1: who are @thing and @user2?".scan(/@([a-z0-9_]+)/i)
=> [["user1"], ["thing"], ["user2"]]
```

In Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("@([a-z0-9_]+)", "RT @user1: who are @thing and @user2?", re.I)
['user1', 'thing', 'user2']
```

In PHP:

```
<?PHP
$matches = array();
preg_match_all(
    "/@([a-z0-9_]+)/i",
    "RT @user1: who are @thing and @user2?",
    $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
?>

Array
(
    [0] => user1
    [1] => thing
    [2] => user2
)
```

Comment: You'll have to add a capture group around the [a-z0-9_], i.e. @([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)

Comment: Thanks, it works fine! One last question: When there must be a space before the "@" or it must be at the beginning, can I use the following expression? "/( |^)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i"

Comment: You could also use a word-boundary \b => /\b@([a-z0-9_]+)/i

Answer (score 2):

try an iterator (findall) with this regex:

```
(@[\w-]+)
```

bye

Comment: simple...nice! combining with scan (ruby) to get an array of matches: text.scan(/@[\w-]+/)

Answer (score 2):

```
/(?<!\w)@(\w+)/
```

The above covers the following scenario, which other answers in this thread do not:

- An @ sign that is not supposed to be a username, e.g. "my email is test@example.com"
- Still allows a username that is at the beginning of a string, e.g. "@username lorem ipsum..."

Comment: Thanks. No one else ever consideres the email address issue!

Answer (score 1):

Is a good idea include twitter text library [1] in your project to resolve this text issues.

```
twttr.txt.extractMentions("a very generic twitt with some @mention");
```

[1] https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js

Answer (score 0):

This should do it (I used named captures for convenience):

.+?@(?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+):[^@]+?@(?[^\s]+)[^@]+?@(?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)

Comment: PHP shows an error message when I use your expression. Something like "missing delimiter . at the end" or so.