# RegEx: Link Twitter-Name Mentions to Twitter in HTML

Tags: html, regex, twitter

I want to do [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740590/regexp-how-to-extract-usernames-out-of-tweets-twitter-com), just a little bit more complicated:

Lets say, I have an HTML input:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" title="Bla @test blubb">Don't break!</a>
Some Twitter Users: @codinghorror, @spolsky, @jarrod_dixon and @blam4c.
You can't reach me at blam4c@example.com.
```

Is there a good RegEx to replace the twitter username mentions by links to twitter, but leave @example (eMail-Adress at the bottom) AND @test (in the link title, i.e. in HTML tags)?

It probably should also try to not add links inside existing links, i.e. not break this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Hello @someone there!</a>
```

My current attempt is to add ">" at the beginning of the string, then use this RegEx:

```
Search:  '/>([^<]*\s)\@([a-z0-9_]+)([\s,.!?])/i'
Replace: '>\1<a href="http://twitter.com/\2">@\2</a>\3'
```

Then remove the ">" I added in step 1.

But that won't match anything but the "@blam4c". I know WHY it does so, that's not the problem.

I would like to find a solution that finds and replaces all twitter user name mentions without destroying the HTML. Maybe it might even be better to code this without RegEx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, keep the angle brackets out of your regexps.

Use a HTML parser and xpath to select the text nodes you are interested in processing, then consider a regexp for matching only @refs in those nodes.

I'll let to other people to try and give a specific answer to the regex part.

Comment: I was afraid you might say this, because it was the same result I came to ;)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with ddaa, there's almost no sane way to attack this without **stripping the html links out first**.

Presumably you'd be starting out with an actual Twitter message, which cannot by *definition* include any manually entered hyperlinks.

For example, here's how I found this question (the link resolves to this question so don't bother clicking it!)

> Some Twitter Users: @codinghorror, @spolsky, @jarrod_dixon and @blam4c. http://bit.ly/2phvZ1

In this case, it's easy:

```
var msg = "Some Twitter Users: @codinghorror, @spolsky, @jarrod_dixon and @blam4c. http://bit.ly/2phvZ1";

var html = Regex.Replace(msg, "(?<!\w)(@(\w+))", 
    "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/$2\">$1</a>");
```

(this might need some tweaking, I'd like to test it against a corpus, but it seems correct for the average Twitter message)

As for your more complicated cases (with HTML markup embedded in the tweets), I have no idea. Way too hard for me.

Answer (score 1):

This regexp might work a bit better: `/\B\@([\w\-]+)/gim`

Here's a jsFiddle example of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2TQsx/4/